# JQuery Editable datagrid suddenly not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, datagrid

Editable datagrid jQuery is not working in firefox after few records inserted in Grails and  ajax call is not working.

here is my code (remote function grails)

```
function saverow(target){

        $("#alertId").empty();
        $('#tt').datagrid('endEdit', getRowIndex(target));
        var row;
         if(tempRow.lookUpValue==""){
                $("#alertId").append("<div class='alert alert-danger'>Lookup value is required</div>");
                return false;
                  }
        if(tempRow.displayValue==""){
                        $("#alertId").append("<div class='alert alert-danger'>Display value is required</div>");
                        return false;
          }


        if (row){
               var parameters = {"id":tempRow.id,"lookUpListType":b,"lookUpValue":tempRow.lookUpValue,"displayValue":tempRow.displayValue,"status":tempRow.activeStatus}
               ${remoteFunction (
                    controller: 'tblLookUp',
                    action: 'saveLookUp',
                    params: 'parameters',
                    update: 'modalOpenBxx12'
            )};
        }
        else
            {
            var parameters = {"id":tempRow.id,"lookUpListType":b,"lookUpValue":tempRow.lookUpValue,"displayValue":tempRow.displayValue,"status":tempRow.activeStatus}
               ${remoteFunction (
                    controller: 'tblLookUp',
                    action: 'saveLookUp',
                    params: 'parameters',
                    update: 'modalOpenBxx12'
            )};
            }
        location.reload();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got Solution

Here in FireFox location.reload is executing  before remote function.